# 3 Level dependent dropdown. The 3rd list won't update while first one changes

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am trying to create a 3 level dependent dropdown select.

Lv1 Options > Lv2 Options > Lv3 Options.

e.g: 
AUDI > Coupé > A5

BMW  > SUV   > X5

I followed [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158744/drupal-7-best-practice-for-a-dynamic-select-list-in-drupal-7) to create a custom module. (I know there is [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module does the job, I prefer do it with custom module)

My problem is that when level 1 option selected, level 2 options DID update, however, level 3 options DID NOT update to reflect level 2's change. I have to manually pick an option in level2 to make level 3 update.

Ideally, if level 1 dropdown select updated, level 2 options will update and level 3 options should also update.

Here is my code, dependent.module :

```
<?php

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function dependent_menu(){
  return array(
    'dependentselect' => array(
      'title' => 'A page to multi level dependent select',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('dependent_page'),
      'access callback' => TRUE, 
    )
  );
}



/**
 * A form with a dropdown whose options are dependent on a
 * choice made in a previous dropdown.
 */
function dependent_page($form, &$form_state) {
  // Get the list of options to populate the first dropdown.
  $options_first  = dependent_first_dropdown_options();
  $options_second = dependent_second_dropdown_options();

  $value_dropdown_first  = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_first'])  ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_first']  : key($options_first);
  $value_dropdown_second = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : key($options_second);

  $form['dropdown_first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'First Dropdown',
    '#options' => $options_first,
    '#default_value' => $value_dropdown_first,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' => 'dependent_first_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'dropdown_second_replace',
    ),
  );

  $form['dropdown_second'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Second Dropdown',
    // The entire enclosing div created here gets replaced when dropdown_first
    // is changed.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown_second_replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => dependent_second_dropdown_options($value_dropdown_first),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : '',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' => 'dependent_second_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'dropdown_third_replace',
    ),
  );

  $form['dropdown_third'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Third Dropdown',
    // The entire enclosing div created here gets replaced when dropdown_first
    // is changed.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown_third_replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => dependent_third_dropdown_options($value_dropdown_second),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_third']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_third'] : '',
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Selects just the second dropdown to be returned for re-rendering
 *
 * @return renderable array (the second dropdown)
 */
function dependent_first_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['dropdown_second'];
}


/**
 * Selects just the second dropdown to be returned for re-rendering
 */
function dependent_second_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['dropdown_third'];
}



/**
 * Helper function to populate the first dropdown. This would normally be
 * pulling data from the database.
 *
 * @return array of options
 */
function dependent_first_dropdown_options() {
  return array(
    'colors' => 'Colors',
    'animals' => 'Animals',
  );
}


/**
 * Helper function to populate the second dropdown.  
 *
 * @param key. This will determine which set of options is returned.
 *
 * @return array of options
 */
function dependent_second_dropdown_options($key = '') {
  $options = array(
    'colors' => array(
       'red' => 'Red',
       'green' => 'Green',
       'blue' => 'Blue'
    ),

    'animals' => array(
      'dog' => 'Dog',
      'cat' => 'Cat',
    ),  
  );

  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  } else {
    return array();
  }
}



/**
 * Helper function to populate the third dropdown. 
 *
 * @param key. This will determine which set of options is returned.
 *
 * @return array of options
 */
function dependent_third_dropdown_options($key = '') {
  $options = array(
    'red' => array(
    'darkred' => 'Dark Red',
    'lightred' => 'Light Red',
    ),

    'green' => array(
      'darkgreen' => 'Dark Green',
      'lightgreen' => 'Light Green',
    ),        

    'blue' => array(
      'darkblue' => 'Dark Blue',
      'lightblue' => 'Light Blue',
    ),

    'dog' => array(
        'bigdog' => 'Big Dog',
        'smalldog' => 'Small Dog',
    ),

    'cat' => array(
        'bigcat' => 'Big cat',
        'smallcat' => 'Small Cat',
    ),

  );

  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  } else {
    return array();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just went through the docs again, realize that since I want to manipulate multiple elements.

I should use a 'bigger' wrapper for ajax replace.

> You can easily replace the entire form if that is easiest. Just add a
>
> ## prefix and #suffix to the entire form array, then set that as the #ajax['wrapper']. (This will allow you to change multiple form elements via a single ajax call.)

--
http://drupal.org/node/752056

Answer (score 1):

You've set #ajax callback event as **'changed'**, but it is not called for the 2 element after it changed, because your ajax callback returns the whole element(changed event is envoked only if you change selected option). 
I'm not sure about proper solution, but as for me, I would have either added custom JS to change element after update, or experiment a little with changing #options for select.
One more variant is to return both form selects on first one change.