# Update multiple fields when one field changed with AJAX dependent dropdown

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm working on a D7 custom form with AJAX dependent dropdown, and I can't figure how to update two fields based on a selection from the first field. Here's the code so far:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 *
 * Form builder function for export form
 */
function mymodule_form($node, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  // Get list of available entity types.
  $entity_options = array('commerce_product' => t('Product'), 'node' => t('Node'));
  $selected_entity_type = isset($form_state['values']['entity_type']) ? $form_state['values']['entity_type'] : key($entity_options);

  $form['entity_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Entity Type'),
    '#description' => t('Select the desired entity type'),
    '#options' => $entity_options,
    '#default_value' => $selected_entity_type,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'bundles-replace'
    ),
  );

  if ($selected_entity_type == 'commerce_product') {
    $bundle_options['product'] = t('Product');
  }
  else {
    // Get available node types.
    $node_types = node_type_get_types();
    $bundle_options = array();

    // Create an array to populate the node options.
    foreach($node_types as $type) {
      $bundle_options[$type->orig_type] = $type->name;
    }
  }

  $bundle_options = _mymodule_get_bundles($selected_entity_type);
  // Get the $selected_bundle based on the entity field. Since there are multiple dependent fields in
  // this form,  we can't really depend on $form_state['values'].
  $selected_bundle = isset($form_state['triggering_element']) && $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'bundle'? $form_state['triggering_element']['#value'] : key($bundle_options);

  $form['bundle'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Bundle'),
    '#description' =>t('Select the content type to export'),
    '#options' => $bundle_options,
    '#default_value' => $selected_bundle,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'fields-replace'
    ),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="bundles-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  $field_options = _mymodule_get_fields($selected_entity_type, $selected_bundle);

  $form['fields'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Fields'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="fields-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => $field_options
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Export'),
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Since the controlling logic for populating the form is in the form builder
 * function, all we do here is select the element and return it to be updated.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Renderable array (the second dropdown)
 */
function mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
  // The returned field depends on the triggering form field.
  switch ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name']) {
    case 'bundle':
      return $form['fields'];
      break;
    case 'entity_type':
      return $form['bundle'];
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Helper function to populate the fields dropdown.
 *
 * @param string $key
 *   This will determine which set of options is returned.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Dropdown options
 */
function _mymodule($entity_type, $bundle) {
  // Get fields for the selected node type.
  $fields = field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle);
  $return = array();

  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $return[$field['field_name']] = $field['label'];
  }

  if (count($return) == 0) {
    $return['none'] = t('No fields for content type');
  }

  return $return;
}

/**
 * Helper function to populate the node_type dropdown.
 *
 * @param string $key
 *   This will determine which set of options is returned.
 *
 * @return array
 *   Dropdown options
 */
function _mymodule_get_bundles($key = '') {
  $return = array();
  if($key == 'commerce_product') {
    $return['product'] = t('Product');
  }
  else {
    $entities = entity_get_info();
    $bundles = $entities[$key]['bundles'];

    foreach ($bundles as $bundle_key => $bundle) {
      $return[$bundle_key] = $bundle['label'];
    }
  }

  return $return;
}
```

So what I want is to update both the `bundle` and `fields` fields when the `entity_type` field is changed. As it is now, the `bundles` field is updated when `entity_type` is changed, and `fields` is changed correctly when `bundles` is changed, but I can't get `fields` to update when `entity_types` is changed. When the code gets to where the `fields` field is built in the form builder function, the `#options` value has the correct values, but the page isn't updated with them. To try to accomplish that, I tried this code based on [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/8530/173):

```
function mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
  // The returned field depends on the triggering form field.
  switch ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name']) {
    case 'bundle':
      return $form['fields'];
      break;
    case 'entity_type':
      return array(
        '#type' => 'ajax',
        '#commands' => array(
          ajax_command_replace("#bundles-replace", render($form['bundles'])),
          ajax_command_replace("#fields-replace", render($form['fields']))
        )
      );
      break;
  }
}
```

but the end result is that the `fields` field completely disappears from the page, even though `$form['fields']` exists at that point in `mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback()`.

Based on [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/43978/173), I also tried replacing the entire form, like so:

```
function mymodule_form($node, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="content-export-form">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  $form['entity_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Entity Type'),
    '#description' => t('Select the desired entity type'),
    '#options' => $entity_options,
    '#default_value' => $selected_entity_type,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'content-export-formt'
    ),
  );
       ...
}

function mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form;
}
```

but that didn't replace either 'bundle`or 'fields` when `entity_type` was updated.

What do I have to change to get the `bundles` and `fields` fields to be updated on the page when `entity_type` is changed?

Thanks.

**UPDATE** . After looking through my code again, I realized I had a typo in the wrapper definition on the `entity` field:

```
'wrapper' => 'content-export-formt'
```

Once I fixed that, it worked, sort of. When I first change the `entity_type` field to `Node`, it changes the `bundle` field values appropriately and sets the options for the `fields` field appropriately. However, when I select a different value in `fields`, instead of replacing the form fields, it adds a new instance of the `entity_type` and `bundle` fields on the page, and this repeats for each time I select a new value from the `bundle` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not be like [this guy](https://xkcd.com/979/), here's how I got it working.

It turns out I was pretty close. The only thing I really had left to do was change the `#wrapper` setting for the `bundle` field to be `content-export-form` as well.. Once I did that, the form worked like I wanted. Here's the final form builder function:

```
function mymodule_form($node, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="content-export-form">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  // Get list of available entity types.
  $entity_options = array('commerce_product' => t('Product'), 'node' => t('Node'));
  $selected_entity_type = isset($form_state['values']['entity_type']) ? $form_state['values']['entity_type'] : key($entity_options);

  $form['entity_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Entity Type'),
    '#description' => t('Select the desired entity type'),
    '#options' => $entity_options,
    '#default_value' => $selected_entity_type,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'content-export-form'
    ),
  );

  if ($selected_entity_type == 'commerce_product') {
    $bundle_options['product'] = t('Product');
  }
  else {
    // Get available node types.
    $node_types = node_type_get_types();
    $bundle_options = array();

    // Create an array to populate the node options.
    foreach($node_types as $type) {
      $bundle_options[$type->orig_type] = $type->name;
    }
  }

  $bundle_options = _mymodule_get_bundles($selected_entity_type);
  // Get the $selected_bundle based on the entity field. Since there are multiple dependent fields in
  // this form,  we can't really depend on $form_state['values'].
  $selected_bundle = isset($form_state['triggering_element']) && $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'bundle'? $form_state['triggering_element']['#value'] : key($bundle_options);

  $form['bundle'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Content Type'),
    '#description' =>t('Select the content type to export'),
    '#options' => $bundle_options,
    '#default_value' => $selected_bundle,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'content-export-form'
    ),
  );

  $field_options = _mymodule_get_fields($selected_entity_type, $selected_bundle);

  $form['fields'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Fields'),
    '#options' => $field_options
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Export'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

and here's the ajax callback function:

```
function mymodule_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
  // We're returning the whole form since multiple fields are being updated.
  return $form;
}
```